# How can one query the Cluster .etl logs thru Powershell?

Tags: powershell-3.0, event-log, windows-clustering

Server 2008 onward the cluster log is stored in 3 different .etl files at "%WinDir%\System32\winevt\logs\"

1. Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering Diagnostic.etl.001
2. Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering Diagnostic.etl.002
3. Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering Diagnostic.etl.003

However, I can't query these files thru `Get-Winevent`

`Get-WinEvent : The C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-FailoverClustering%4Diagnostic.etl.001 file does not appear to be a valid log file. Specify only .evtx, .etl, or .evt files as values of the 
Path parameter.`

Am I missing something? Is there another way of querying these .etl filesthru Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't read these files directly as far as I know, you have to dump the contents into the cluster.log file to get a human readable output using Get-ClusterLog or cluster log /gen on 2008 systems:

[Understanding the Cluster Debug Log in 2008](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2010/04/13/understanding-the-cluster-debug-log-in-2008.aspx)